# Model Explainability Monitor Job fails for endpoint having two production variants

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, mlops

I have a sagemaker endpoint with two production variants (for A/B testing). After testing, one of the variant gets zero traffic and other gets 100% of the traffic. This results in zero data capturing for the first variant. When model explainability job runs, it searches for captured for the variant with zero traffic as well which causes it to fail.

Is there a way to run model explainability monitoring job with an endpoint having two production variants?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Model Monitor works with endpoint with single variants. If you are looking to do shadow deployment I would refer you look at this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-shadow-ml-models-in-amazon-sagemaker/)